# How to trim and extract JSON string via C# RegEx?

Tags: c#, regex, json, json.net

I have a json string that I will like to grab only the array in the data node. Do I trim using RegEx or what is the best way to extract that portion of the json string?

Here is a sample:

```
{
   "Data":[
      {
         "Title":"Test Item 1",
         "Icon":"pdf",
         "PublicationDate":"2013-05-08T18:23:18.037Z"
      },
      {
         "Title":"Test Item 2",
         "Icon":"pdf",
         "PublicationDate":"2013-05-08T18:23:38.177Z"
      }
   ],
   "Count":67
}
```

Below is what I want to end up with:

```
   [
      {
         "Title":"Test Item 1",
         "Icon":"pdf",
         "PublicationDate":"2013-05-08T18:23:18.037Z"
      },
      {
         "Title":"Test Item 2",
         "Icon":"pdf",
         "PublicationDate":"2013-05-08T18:23:38.177Z"
      }
   ]
```

How can I do this properly? Sometimes the json string already comes as I need with only the array in the data node, so the logic has to be smart enough to ignore it if it already comes in that format. The reason is because I am feeding both cases to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(json)`.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would be a million times easier to just deserialize it then grab the array content out.. rather than stripping the json content, debugging malformed json, etc.

Comment: But the json string can come in either form, so I do not know beforehand whether it has a data node or is just an array. It's a generic method so it has to handle both json strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, it seems that this is what you need:

```
var jToken=JToken.Parse(data);
JArray arr;
switch(jToken.Type)
{
    case JTokenType.Array:
        arr=(JArray)jToken;
        break;
    case JTokenType.Object:
        arr=(JArray)((JObject)jToken)["Data"];
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception();
}
var output=arr.ToString();
```

Comment: How would I test if there is a "Data" node. Sometimes the json returned just gives me the array with no data or count nodes.